# Find \x in a python string

Tags: python, unicode

I am unable to replace \x in a python string with ''

```
x ='\x01'
re.sub('\x','',x)
```

gives ValueError: invalid \x escape.

```
isinstance(x,unicode)
```

gives False.

```
def remove_non_ascii_2(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', '', text)

x = '\x01'
remove_non_ascii_2(x)
```

returns '\x01' with no effect

How can I replace '\x' with the empty string?

Comment: `x = '\x01'` -- this is the character `\x01` at ascii point `1` (it's an ascii character still, not just unicode). `\x` does not exist in the string. The error you're getting is because you need to do `re.sub(r'\x', '' x)` but that still won't work.

Comment: Yes. I get error: bogus escape: '\\x'

Comment: Still, your `remove_non_ascii` doesn't remove non ascii. Those code points are all literal ascii code points.

Comment: You might need to take a step back and explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve. You probably just need to display your data differently, not attempt to modify it.

Comment: I have to remove this character. I have column  with values - [nan, '\x01', '0.0', '1.0', 0.0, 1.0]. This needs to be summed.

Comment: So what is `\x01` supposed to represent in your sum? The number 1? If so, try running it through [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

Comment: Is that a literal ascii code point `'\x01'` or the representation `r'\x01' == '\\x01'`? The difference is very important.

Comment: @glibdud \x01 supposed to represent 1. I need to atleast find the locations of those character such that I can write map function to run through ord(). Don't you think so?

Comment: @FHTMitchell I don't understand regex or unicode enough to ans ur question. It looks like a '\x01' when print my column as a list: [nan, '\x01', '0.0', '1.0', 0.0, 1.0]

Comment: Well that's an issue with your data. Since you have a mix of floats, strings representing floats, and strings containing bytes representing integers, it's not a particularly simple problem.

Comment: That is neither a regex nor a unicode question. It is a fundamental python string question.

Comment: I just want to point out that using python 3.x enforces the notion of string encoding more strictly than 2.7 and you should force yourself into learning it. To me the important distinction was learning that a python string does not represent an array of 8 bit values like it does in C, but rather a list of Unicode code points that are *sometimes* 8 bit values. If you think about the in-memory representation rather than just what prints out in your terminal window, it'll help you understand the problem a lot better.

Comment: ok. I will learn. I have patched something together with ord() for now. final['is_paid_lead'].map(lambda x:x if x!=x else(ord(x) if x=='\x01' else float(x))).value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like the biggest problem you have is an inconsistent data source. In the given list of values you have regular floating point values: `nan`, `1.0`, `0.0` strings that represent floats: `"1.0"`, `"0.0"` and strings that contain integers as binary values: `"\x01"`

It's relatively trivial to sort out the floats from the strings with something like:

```
if type(item) == float:
    #do stuff
```

Furthermore if you want to sort out the `nan` values (a special type of float) you can do this:

```
if type(item) == float 
    if item == float('nan'):
        #do other stuff
    else:
        #do stuff
```

Sorting out the strings is a little trickier as there are many ways to represent a value using a string.The regular string to float conversion using `float("1.0")` works if your string already looks like a float [(rules for looking like a float)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). If however the value is represented by the binary value of the string characters (it sounds like this may be the case) you will have to find a way to differentiate between the two types of string. This may be as simple as first trying to call `float(item)` and catching errors when the format doesn't match the "like a float" criteria. Then assuming you only have a single character you could use `ord(item)` to return the binary representation of said character. This might look something like this:

```
try:
    converted = float(item)
catch ValueError:
    if len(item) == 1:
        converted = ord(item)
    else:
        #determine how to handle multi character values
```

Comment: Yes I did something similar : `final['is_paid_lead'].map(lambda x:x if x!=x else(ord(x) if x=='\x01' else float(x)))`